# Заменяя ядра сети

Tags: маршрутизация, vpn, cisco, маршрутизатор

Постепенно в нашей компании возникает вопрос о замене ядра сети. В головном офисе стоит древняя 2851, в удалённых офисах 800 серии, удалённые офисы подключены посредством DMVPN. Хотелось бы заменить ядро на hp, в связи с этим вопрос, почитал что у hp есть схожая технология DVPN, возможно ли обьеденить hp и cisco 800 серии, без замены оборудования в филиалах?  Или если нет, то посоветуйте маршрутизатор на замену 2800, не cisco.